# Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null value (mysql to textbox)

Tags: c#, mysql

My friend wants to transfer her data from the database to a textbox to her program in c# but it gets an error of this:

> "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null
>   values."

Here is the code by the way:

```
sql_command = new MySqlCommand("select sum(lt_min_hours) as TotalLate from tbl_late where (late_date between '" + date_start + "' and '" + date_to + "' and empid = '" + empid + "')", sql_connect);
sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();            

if (sql_reader.Read())
{
    textBox_tlate.Text = sql_reader.GetString("TotalLate");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Data.");
}
```

Comment: What happens if you executed this SQL statement against the database outside of your C# solution?

Comment: On which line does the error occur? The error clearly states that some object is null, so most likely your sql query isn't filling your reader.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum);

> `SUM()` returns `NULL` if there were no matching rows.

But first of all, You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

After that, you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar) instead of `ExecuteReader` which is returns only one column with one row. In your case, this is exactly what you want.

```
textBox_tlate.Text = sql_command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test for DbNull.Value against your field before assigning it to the textbox

```
if (sql_reader.Read())
{
    if(!sql_reader.IsDbNull(sql_reader.GetOrdinal("TotalLate")))
        textBox_tlate.Text = sql_reader.GetString("TotalLate");
}
```

**EDIT**
According to your comment, nothing happens, so the WHERE condition fails to retrieve any record and the result is a NULL.
Looking at your query I suppose that your variables containing dates are converted to a string in an invalid format. This could be fixed using a ToString and a proper format string (IE: yyyy-MM-dd) but the correct way to handle this is through a parameterized query

```
sql_command = new MySqlCommand(@"select sum(lt_min_hours) as TotalLate 
                 from tbl_late 
                 where (late_date between @init and @end and empid = @id", sql_connect);
sql_command.Parameters.Add("@init", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = date_start;
sql_command.Parameters.Add("@end", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = date_end;
sql_command.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = empid;
sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();
```

This assumes that `date_start` and `date_end` are DateTime variables and `empid` is an integer one.  In this way, the parsing of the parameters is done by the MySql engine that knows how to handle a DateTime variable. Instead your code uses the automatic conversion made by the Net Framework that, by default, uses your locale settings to convert a date to a string.

Comment: There are no longer any errors but whenever I click the button that shows the sum(late_min_hours), nothing happens.

Comment: This means that your query doesn't retrieve any row to SUM and the result is NULL. Check your WHERE condition. What are the type of date_start and date_end? What is their values? Usually these problems are avoided using parameterized queries